# Compute the gradient of sum with $x_{k+1}$ and $x_{k-1}$

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I'm trying to compute the gradient of $E_{(x)}$ but I don't know how to treat to $x_{k+1}$ and $x_{k-1}$, x is a vector.

$\forall x = x_{k} \in \Bbb R^n$, $E_{(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k})^2$

Do I handle it by doing:

$\nabla E_{(x)} =\frac{\partial E_{(x)}}{\partial x} = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k}) \times 1+1-2$

Or by:

$\nabla E_{(x)} =\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial E_{(x)}}{\partial x_{k}} \\
    \frac{\partial E_{(x)}}{\partial x_{k+1}}  \\
    \frac{\partial E_{(x)}}{\partial x_{k-1}}  \\
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k}) \\
    2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k})  \\
    -4\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k})  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

I am so confused... help!

Comment: The gradient has components $\frac{\partial E}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial E}{\partial x_2},\frac{\partial E}{\partial x_3},...,\frac{\partial E}{\partial x_n}$.

Comment: $\nabla E_{(x)} =\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{\partial E_{(x)}}{\partial x_{k}} \\
    \frac{\partial E_{(x)}}{\partial x_{k+1}}  \\
    \frac{\partial E_{(x)}}{\partial x_{k-1}}  \\
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k}) \\
    2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k})  \\
    -4\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}+x_{k-1}-2x_{k})  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$ is the right answer.